# SQL Server : update record and then insert the same record with updated information

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

This is what I am trying to accomplish: I need to update one record (w EndDate) and then insert that same record with updated information (w new Revision, StartDate and Blank EndDate). I am stuck on how to accomplish this.

I have a SQL Statement that I have to gather certain records that needs to be updated.

Sample records.. there is about 4500 records that need to be updated:

```
 PartID   Revision  StartDate    EndDate
 ----------------------------------------
 S2334D      1      08/20/2017
 Y423DS      A      08/18/2017
 KL432W      01     08/18/2017
```

To this:

```
 PartID   Revision  StartDate    EndDate
 -------------------------------------------
 S2334D      1      08/20/2017   03/20/2018
 S2334D      2      03/20/2018   
 Y423DS      A      08/18/2017   03/20/2018
 Y423DS      1      03/20/2018   
 KL432W      01     08/18/2017   03/20/2018
 KL432W      02     08/18/2017
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest either an SP that explicitly takes arguments for the update, then uses the updated record to perform the insert, or an update trigger.

```
    create proc p_revise(@partID, @rev, @otherfields)
    as
    update Part set EndDate = getutcdate() 
          where PartID = @partID AND Revision = @rev
    insert into Part (PartID, Revision, StartDate)
         select @partID, @rev + 1, EndDate from Part
         where PartID = @partID AND Revision = @rev
```

Something like that.
You will need something smarter than rev + 1 if your revisions are not just numeric, as shown in your example.

Alternatively, if this is a one-off thing, you could create an update trigger that performs an insert in the same table based on the 'inserted' table.

```
create trigger Part_update on Part for update as
    insert into Part (PartID, Revision, StartDate)
             select PartID, Revision + 1, EndDate from inserted
```

Somewhat dangerous as a permanent solution though.

Comment: I have a SQL Statement that I have to gather certain records that needs to be updated.

Comment: In that case you should use the first solution posted by Rumbleweed, just replace the (PartID =@partID) with (PartID in ( select partid from....{your query})

Comment: Ok I will give that a try. Thank you so very much.